# Combining duplicate rows in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, sapb1

I posted this question already on another forum, but have not got any responses yet and requiring a solution quickly: https://answers.sap.com/questions/384242/combining-duplicate-lines-in-crystal.html

For various reasons to do with product numbering customization on our SAP B1 system, we can have no more than two of our standard items on a row in a sales order or invoice. All other items, such as accessories and non-numbered items we can put as many on a row as we want. To save any questions, this process cannot be avoided.

The issue is that this means we get some very strange looking invoices. For example if I sell 15 of our standard item 'A' and 15 of our standard item 'B' with 30 accessories to match, I can either bill out 15 lines each containing one 'A' and 15 lines each containing one 'B' then one line containing all the 30 accessories. Otherwise, I can bill out 7 lines each containing two of 'A', then one line containing the 15th A, then 7 lines each containing two of 'B', then one line containing the 15th B, and finally one line containing 30 accessories.

Is there any way that, in the case that an invoice contains rows with identical length, width, height and colour (or any other fields if it makes it easier), crystal can be configured to combine the rows into one and return the sum of the quantities and the sum of the prices in the relevant columns?

Added images below:

[image: Shown with dummy items]
[image: Crystal Layout]

Comment: Have you tried the GROUPing feature in Crystal?

Comment: sample layout would help along with dummy data

Comment: Added images now - does that help?

Comment: Thanks @Grantly - that was perfect